# Lua - Reflection - Get list of functions/fields on an object?

Tags: c++, reflection, function, object, lua

I'm new to Lua and dealing with Lua as a scripting language in an alpha release of a program. The developer is unresponsive and I need to get a list of functions provided by some C++ objects which are accessible from the Lua code.

Is there any easy way to see what fields and functions these objects expose?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In Lua, to view the members of a object, you can use:

```
for key,value in pairs(o) do
    print("found member " .. key);
end
```

Unfortunately I don't know if this will work for objects imported from C++.

Comment: Wow, so simple. It works 100%, thanks so much! You have no idea how helpful this is. :)

One more thing - can you also get a list of arguments for the functions?

Comment: Not that I know.  I wonder what you could find doing a dll export on the compiled c++.

Comment: I have tried that, but searching through the function names didn't even find the functions that I know exist, unfortunately.

Comment: A DLL based module will often only export the single function `luaopen_modulename()` which constructs the module's table and returns it to the machinery that implements `require()`. The code implementing the actual functions in the module is usually not exported because it can only be called within the context of a running Lua interpreter state.

Answer (score 26):

If allowed in the environment, looking at the metatable of the exported C++ object can help:

```
for key,value in pairs(getmetatable(o)) do
    print(key, value)
end
```

Answer (score 10):

Print all the globals:

```
    -- globals.lua
    -- show all global variables

    local seen={}

    function dump(t,i)
        seen[t]=true
        local s={}
        local n=0
        for k in pairs(t) do
            n=n+1 s[n]=k
        end
        table.sort(s)
        for k,v in ipairs(s) do
            print(i,v)
            v=t[v]
            if type(v)=="table" and not seen[v] then
                dump(v,i.."\t")
            end
        end
    end

    dump(_G,"")
```

source: http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo

Output:

```
    _G
    _VERSION
    assert
    bit32
        arshift
        band
        bnot
        bor
        btest
        bxor
        extract
        lrotate
        lshift
        replace
        rrotate
        rshift
    collectgarbage
    coroutine
        create
        isyieldable
        resume
        running
        status
        wrap
        yield
    debug
        gethook
        getinfo
        getlocal
        getmetatable
        getupvalue
        getuservalue
        sethook
        setlocal
        setmetatable
        setupvalue
        setuservalue
        traceback
        upvalueid
        upvaluejoin
    dump
    error
    getmetatable
    io
        write
    ipairs
    load
    math
        abs
        acos
        asin
        atan
        atan2
        ceil
        cos
        cosh
        deg
        exp
        floor
        fmod
        frexp
        huge
        ldexp
        log
        log10
        max
        maxinteger
        min
        mininteger
        modf
        pi
        pow
        rad
        random
        randomseed
        sin
        sinh
        sqrt
        tan
        tanh
        tointeger
        type
        ult
    next
    os
        clock
        date
        difftime
        exit
        setlocale
        time
    pairs
    pcall
    print
    rawequal
    rawget
    rawlen
    rawset
    select
    setmetatable
    string
        byte
        char
        dump
        find
        format
        gmatch
        gsub
        len
        lower
        match
        pack
        packsize
        rep
        reverse
        sub
        unpack
        upper
    table
        concat
        insert
        move
        pack
        remove
        sort
        unpack
    tonumber
    tostring
    type
    utf8
        char
        charpattern
        codepoint
        codes
        len
        offset
    xpcall
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the same vein as the answer Mr Stinky gave but a whole lot more information.

I made the below code originally for a running from a web server but have added the capability to run on lua for windows

on a web server options are passed in query string ?loadmodules=no&module=_G

in program form options are passed on command line functs loadmodules no module _G

if run with no arguments all modules in pkgpath are loaded and parsed

```
#!/usr/bin/lua
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--|Functs.lua load available modules parse tables give write to HTML|
--|Table Of Contents, modules, available functions, strings etc..   |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
-- CONFIGURE----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
local sPkgPath = "/usr/lib/lua" --look here for modules to load in addition to the intrinsic ones
local sWpkgPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Lua\\5.1\\lua\\" --package path for windows
local sURLsearch = "http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/" --for lua standard functions search this site
local iMaxStr = 1024 -- maximum characters in a string printed to HTML table
local sFileOut = "functs.html"
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
local tQuery = {} --key,val pairs of arguments
local sQuery = "" --string of arguments ex:'?modload=no&module=_G.math...'
local sResults = "" --Results of each step through
local sEnv = "web" --running on a web server?
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

----------------------------FUNCTIONS START----------------------------------------------
local function a2m_m2a(addr_member)
    --turns members into addresses; addresses back into members
    return addr_member
end

local function PrRes(sVal)
    --cats results strings
    sResults = sResults .. sVal
end

local function errorHandler( err )
   PrRes(" ERROR:" .. err .. " ")
  --print(debug.traceback())
end

local function putOutput(tData, iCt)
--keys are integer indices, values to iCt written, if iCt = nil whole table written
    for k, v in ipairs(tData) do
        if iCt == nil or k <= iCt then
            io.write (v) --write to std out could be changed here, or as below we change stdout file
        end
    end
end

local function parse_url(s)
--http://www.flashair-developers.com/en/support/forum/#/discussion/880/getting-query-string-parameters-from-an-http-request-in-lua/
--splits on '=' and '&' puts argument string into named keys with value [Key1] = (val1)&[Key2] = (val2)
--ex: Key1=va1&Key2=val2
    local ans = {[0]=""}

----FUNCTIONS for parse_url -----------------------------------------------------
    local function decode(s)
        s = s:gsub('+', ' ')
        s = s:gsub('%%(%x%x)', function(h) return string.char(tonumber(h, 16)) end)
        return s
    end
----END FUNCTIONS for parse_url --------------------------------------------------

    if s == nil then return ans end
    --s = s:match('%s+(.+)')

    for k,v in s:gmatch('([^&=]+)=([^&=]*)&?' ) do
    --2 capture groups all chars (not '&' or '=') '=' all chars (not '&' or '=') followed by '' or '&' or '?'
        ans[ k ] = decode(v)
    end
    return ans
end

local function tableByName(tName)
    --find the longest match possible to an actual table
    --Name comes in as (table) tName.var so we can pass back out the name found PITA
    --returns the table found (key and value)
    local ld = {}
    local sMatch = ""
    local kMatch = nil
    local vMatch = nil

----FUNCTIONS for tableByName -----------------------------------------------------
    local function search4Str(n, k, v)
        local sKey = tostring(k)
        if string.find (n, sKey,1,true) then
            if sKey:len() > sMatch:len() then sMatch = sKey kMatch = k  vMatch = v end
            --find the longest match we can
        end
    end
----END FUNCTIONS for tableByName -------------------------------------------------

    if tName.val ~= nil and tName.val ~= "" then
        for k, v in pairs(_G) do --_G check both since some tables are only in _G or package.loaded
            search4Str(tName.val, k, v)
        end
        for k, v in pairs(package.loaded) do --package.loaded
            search4Str(tName.val, k, v)
        end
        if not string.find (sMatch, "_G",1,true) then sMatch = "_G." .. sMatch end -- put the root _G in if not exist
        if kMatch and vMatch then ld[kMatch] = vMatch tName.val = sMatch return ld end
    end
    tName.val = "_G"
    return package.loaded --Not Found return default
end

local function get_common_branches(t, tRet)
    --load t 'names(values)' into keys
    --strip off long paths then iterate value if it exists
    --local tRet={}
    local sBranch = ""
    local tName
    for k in pairs(t) do
            tName={["val"]=k}
            tableByName(tName)
            sBranch = tName.val
            if tRet[sBranch] == nil then
                tRet[sBranch] = 1 --first instance of this branch
            else
                tRet[sBranch] = tRet[sBranch] + 1
            end
    end
end

local function pairsByPairs (t, tkSorted)
    --tkSorted should be an already sorted (i)table with t[keys] in the values
    --https://www.lua.org/pil/19.3.html
    --!!Note: table sort default function does not like numbers as [KEY]!!
    --see *sortbyKeys*cmp_alphanum*
      --for n in pairs(t) do table.insert(kSorted, n) end
      --table.sort(kSorted, f)

    local i = 0      -- iterator variable
    local iter = function ()   -- iterator function
        i = i + 1
        if tkSorted[i] == nil then return nil
            else return tkSorted[i], t[tkSorted[i]]
        end
    end
    return iter
end

local function sortbyKeys(t, tkSorted)
    --loads keys of (t) into values of tkSorted
    --and then sorts them
    --tkSorted has integer keys (see ipairs)
----FUNCTIONS for sortByKeys -------------
    local cmp_alphanum = function (op1, op2)
                            local type1= type(op1)
                            local type2 = type(op2)
                            if type1 ~= type2 then
                                return type1 < type2
                            else
                                return op1 < op2
                            end
                        end
----END FUNCTIONS for sortByKeys ---------
    for n in pairs(t) do table.insert(tkSorted, n) end
    table.sort(tkSorted, cmp_alphanum)--table.sort(tkSorted)
end

local function load_modules(sPkgRoot, sWinPkgRoot)
    --attempt to load all found modules
    --Modules may depend on other modules
    --Supresses print, os.exit, rawset
    --Ignores *.luac
    PrRes("Functions Suspended, ")
    local orig ={osexit = _G.os.exit, print = _G.print, rawset = _G.rawset} --save original functions for later restoration

    _G.rawset = function(t, i, v) --orig.print ("rawset!")
                                    if _G[i] == v then
                                        orig.rawset(t,i,"_G["..tostring(i).."] !DUP!") --Don't allow global table to be copied
                                    else
                                        orig.rawset(t,i,v)
                                    end
                            end
    _G.os.exit  = function() error(999) end --don't exit whole program just this function

    _G.print    = function()end --don't print

    local st = io.popen("find "..sPkgRoot.." -type f -iname '*.so' -o -type f -iname '*.lua'" .." 2> nul")

    if not st:read(0) then --find didn't work try windows dir instead
        st = io.popen("dir /b /s " .."\""..sWinPkgRoot.."\\*.lua\" " .. "\""..sWinPkgRoot.."\\*.so\" " ) --simple output, subdir
    end
    if st:read(0) then
        for module in st:lines() do
            if (module) then
                if not string.find (module, ".luac", 1, true) then --don't load precompiled code
                    local ok, res = pcall(loadfile(module))--protected call
                end
            end
        end
    end

    _G.os.exit  = orig.osexit
    _G.print    = orig.print
    _G.rawset   = orig.rawset
    PrRes("Functions Restored, ")
end

local function dtTag(sType)
--convert named type; 'number'.. to short type '[n]...'
--if '?' supplied print out datatype key; number = [n]...
    local retType = "?"
    local typ = {
                ["nil"] = "nil",
                ["boolean"]  = "b",
                ["number"] = "n",
                ["string"] = "s",
                ["userdata"] = "u",
                ["function"] = "f",
                ["thread"] = "thr",
                ["table"] = "t"
                }
    if sType == "?" then retType = "Datatypes: " end
    for k,v in pairs(typ) do
        if sType == k then
            retType = v break
        elseif (sType == "?") then
            retType = retType .. "  [" ..v.. "] = " .. k
        end
    end
    return " [" ..retType.. "] "
end

local function dump_Tables(tBase,sFunc, tSeen, tRet)
    --Based on: http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo?globals
    --Recurse through tBase tables copying all found Tables
    local sSep=""
    local ld={}

    if sFunc ~= "" then sSep = "." end

    for k, v in pairs(tBase) do
        k = tostring(k)
        if k ~= "loaded" and type(v) == "table" and not tSeen[v] then
            tSeen[v]=sFunc
            tRet[sFunc..sSep .. k] = a2m_m2a(v) --place all keys into ld[i]=value
            dump_Tables(v, sFunc .. sSep .. k, tSeen, tRet)
        end
    end
--print("tables dumped")
end

local function dump_Functions(tBase)
    --Based on: http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo?globals
    --We already recursed through tBase copying all found tables
    --we look up the table by name and then (ab)use a2m_m2a() to load the address
    --after finding the table by address in tBase we will put the table address of tFuncs in its place

    for k,v in pairs(tBase) do
        local tTable = a2m_m2a(v)
        local tFuncs = {}
        --print(type(tTable))

        for key, val in pairs(tTable) do
            if key ~= "loaded" then
                tFuncs[dtTag(type(val)) .. tostring(key) ]= val --put the name and value in our tFuncs table
            end
        end
        tBase[k] = a2m_m2a(tFuncs) -- copy the address back to tBase
    end

--print("functions dumped")
end

local function html_Table(tBase, tkSorted, sId, fHeader, sTitle, iCols, fCellCond, fCell, fFooter, fOut)
    --[[Prints HTML <table>
        tBase,    the table of items you want in your table [key] contains the cell data
        tkSorted, the key sorted values of tBase (tkSorted keys are (i) based (see: ipairs)
        sID,      ID of div tag
        fHeader,  function returning <DIV></DIV>
        sTitle,   title of the table
        iCols,    number of cells wide
        fCellCond,    if return (TRUE) cell is displayed, fCellCond(k, v, n, iCells, i)
        fCell,    function returning contents of cell
        fFooter,  function returning tags at the end of the </table>
        fOut,     function to print the table[integer]=HTML_DATA based output
    --]]
    local oTbl={}
    local i = 1
    local strName=""
    local iCells = 0
    local n = 0 --counts columns
    oTbl[i]=fHeader(sId,sTitle)
    i = i + 1 oTbl[i] = "<table><tr><th colspan='"..iCols.."'>"..sTitle.."</th></tr>\r\n"
    for k, v in pairsByPairs(tBase,tkSorted ) do

        strName= tostring(k)
        if fCellCond(k, v, n, iCells, i) then
            if n == 0 then
                i = i + 1 oTbl[i] = "\t<tr>\r\n"
            end
            n = n + 1 i = i + 1 iCells = iCells + 1
            oTbl[i] = "\t\t"..fCell(strName, v, sTitle).."\r\n"
            if n >= iCols then
                n = 0
                i = i + 1
                oTbl[i] = "\t</tr>\r\n"
            end
            fOut(oTbl, i)
            i = 0
        end
    end

    if n ~= 0 then
        i = i + 1 oTbl[i] = "\t</tr>\r\n"
    end
    i = i + 1 oTbl[i] = "</table>\r\n" .. fFooter(strName)
    fOut(oTbl, i)
    return iCells
end

local function html_function_tables(tBase, tkSortTbase, fOut, iCols)
    --print a table of functions for every module in tBase
    local strName=""
    local iCt = 0
    local tFuncs = {}
    local tkSorted = {}

----FUNCTIONS for Funct Html-----------------------------------------------------
        local function fCellTrue(k)
        --return tostring(k) == strName
        return true
    end

    local function fTableCell(strName, value, sTitle)
        local sHref = ""
        local sType = type(value)
        local sPkg = string.match (sTitle, ".+%p(%a+%P)")
        local sVal = ""
        --strName = tostring(strName)
        if string.len(strName) > iMaxStr then
                strName=string.sub(strName,1 , iMaxStr).."....."  --Truncate strings longer than iMaxStr
        end
        if sPkg ~= nil and string.find (";debug;package;string;coroutine;io;math;os;table;", ";"..sPkg..";") then
            sHref = "<a href='"..sURLsearch .. string.sub(strName,6) .. "'>?</a>" --remove [f] from beginning
        end

        if nil ~= string.find (";string;number;userdata;boolean;", sType, 1, true) then

            sVal = tostring(value)

            if string.len(sVal) > iMaxStr then
                sVal=string.sub(sVal,1 , iMaxStr).."....." --Truncate strings longer than iMaxStr
            end

            return "</tr><td colspan='"..iCols.."'>".. sHref ..strName.." : "..sVal.."</td><tr>"
        else
            return  "<td><a>"..strName.."</a>".. sHref .. "</td>"
        end
    end

    local function fPageAnchor(sId, strTitle)
        local sHref = ""
        local sAddr = ""
        local sModload = tQuery.modload
        if not sModload then sModload = "" end

        local sStyle = "'style='display:block;text-decoration: none"
        if os.getenv("SERVER_NAME") and os.getenv("SCRIPT_NAME") then
            sAddr = "http://"..os.getenv("SERVER_NAME") .."/".. os.getenv("SCRIPT_NAME") .."?modload=".. sModload
            sHref="<a href='"..sAddr.."&module="..strTitle..sStyle.."'>" .."Module: " .. strTitle.. "</a>"
        else
            sHref = "Module: " .. strTitle
        end

        return  "<div id='"..sId.."'style='color:#0000FF'><h3>"..sHref.."</h3></div>\r\n"
    end

    local function fPageFooter(strName)
        return "<p><a href='#toc'>^</a></p><BR /><BR />"
    end
----END FUNCTIONS for Funct Html--------------------------------------------------

    for key, val in pairsByPairs(tBase, tkSortTbase) do
        strName=tostring(key)
        tkSorted = {}
        tFuncs = a2m_m2a(val)
        sortbyKeys(tFuncs, tkSorted)

        iCt = iCt + html_Table(tFuncs,tkSorted, strName, fPageAnchor, strName, iCols, fCellTrue, fTableCell, fPageFooter, fOut)
    end
    return iCt
end


local function html_toc_tables(tBase, tkSortTbase, fOut, iCols)

    local iCt = 0

----FUNCTIONS for TOC Html-----------------------------------------------------
    local function fTableCell(strName)
        return  "<td><a href='#" .. strName .. "'style='display:block;text-decoration: none'>" .. strName.. "</a></td>"
    end

    local function fCellTrue()
        return true
    end

    local function fFooter()
        return "<BR /><b>" .. dtTag("?") .. "</b><BR /><BR /><BR /><BR /><BR /><BR />"
    end

    local function fPageAnchor(sId, strTitle)
        return  "<div id='"..sId.."'><p></p></div>\r\n"
    end
----END FUNCTIONS for TOC Html--------------------------------------------------

    iCt = html_Table(tBase, tkSortTbase, "toc", fPageAnchor, "* Modules Found * Lua Ver. ".._VERSION, iCols, fCellTrue, fTableCell, fFooter, fOut)

    return iCt
end

local function main (sPackage)

    local tSeen= {}
    local tcBase = {}
    local tkSortCbase = {}
    local tMods= {}
    local tkSortMods = {}

    local iCtF = 0

    if not sPackage then sPackage = "_G" end

    putOutput( { --header for html document
        [1] = "<!DOCTYPE html>\r\n<html><head>\r\n<style>\r\n",
        [2] = "\ttable, th, td {border: 1px solid black;}\r\n",
        [3] = "\ttable tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #C4C4C4;}\r\n",
        [4] = "\ttable tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color:#EFEFEF;}\r\n",
        [5] = "</style>\r\n</head><body>\r\n"
    } )
    PrRes("Dump Tables: ")
    xpcall( function()dump_Tables(tableByName({["val"] = sPackage}),"", tSeen, tMods) end , errorHandler )
    tSeen = nil
    PrRes("ok, ")

    PrRes("Dump Functions: ")
    xpcall( function()dump_Functions(tMods)end , errorHandler )
    PrRes("ok, ")

    PrRes("Common Branches: ")
    get_common_branches(tMods, tcBase)
    PrRes("ok, ")

    PrRes("Sorting Branches: ")
    sortbyKeys(tcBase, tkSortCbase)
    sortbyKeys(tMods, tkSortMods)
    PrRes("ok, ")

    PrRes("Print TOC: ")
    iCtF = html_toc_tables(tcBase, tkSortCbase, putOutput, 3)
    tcBase= nil tkSortCbase= nil
    PrRes(iCtF .." ok, ")

    PrRes("Print Functions: ")
    iCtF = html_function_tables(tMods, tkSortMods, putOutput, 6)
    PrRes(iCtF .." ok, ")

end
----------------------------FUNCTIONS END--------------------------------------------------

if os.getenv("SERVER_NAME") == nil then
    sEnv="other"
else --sEnv == web
    --Send response header as soon as we load
    io.write ("Status: 200 OK\r\nKeep-Alive: timeout=60\r\nContent-Type:text/html\r\nLast-Modified:Sun, 11 Jan 2099 01:01:99 GMT\r\n\r\n") -- end of response)
end

if sQuery == "" then --load arguments from query string if web; or arg[] if not
    if sEnv == "web" then
        sQuery = os.getenv("QUERY_STRING")
    else --Load arguments from arg[] list arg[1]=arg[2]&arg[3]=arg[4]&..
    for k,v in pairs({...}) do
            sQuery = sQuery .. v
            if math.fmod (k, 2) == 0 then
                sQuery = sQuery .. "&"
            else
                sQuery = sQuery .. "="
            end
        end
    end
end

tQuery = parse_url(sQuery)
--[[print(sQuery)
for k,v in pairs(tQuery) do
print ("[", k ,"]=", v)
end]]

if sQuery ~= "modloadno" and tQuery.modload ~= "no" then
    PrRes("Load Modules: ")
    xpcall( function()load_modules(sPkgPath,sWpkgPath)end, errorHandler )
    --load_modules(sPkgPath)
    PrRes("ok, ")
end

PrRes("Main; ")
if sEnv ~= "web" then
    print("Fileout: " .. sFileOut)
    io.output(sFileOut)
end

local ok, res = pcall(main,tQuery.module)

if not ok then
    if sEnv ~= "web" then
        print("Status: 500 Internal Server Error\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n" .. res .. "\r\n")
    else
        print("Error: " .. res)
    end
end

PrRes("DONE")

io.write("<p> Query: " .. sQuery .. ";; " .. sResults .."</p>")
```

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvtvk.png)