# Lua object introspection

Tags: c++, lua, introspection

I used [lualite](http://code.google.com/p/lualite/) to wrap the following object in lua:

```
class SpriteComponent : public Component
{
public:
    SpriteComponent();

    std::string name() const;
    std::string textureId() const;
    void setTextureId(const std::string& id);
    int spriteCoordX() const;
    void setSpriteCoordX(int value);
    int spriteCoordY() const;
    void setSpriteCoordY(int value);
};
```

The binding code:

```
module(L,
    class_<SpriteComponent>("SpriteComponent")
        .constructor("new")
        .def("name", &SpriteComponent::name)
        .property("textureId", 
            &SpriteComponent::textureId, &SpriteComponent::setTextureId)
        .property("spriteCoordX", 
            &SpriteComponent::spriteCoordX, &SpriteComponent::setSpriteCoordX)
        .property("spriteCoordY", 
            &SpriteComponent::spriteCoordY, &SpriteComponent::setSpriteCoordY)
);
```

Is there a way (either on the lua side or the C++ side) to get a list of properties? If I list the pairs in the resulting table, I only get `name` and `__instance`.

```
local o = SpriteComponent.new()
for key,value in pairs(o) do
    print("found member " .. key);
end
```

I even tried some of [these](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TableSerialization) table printers, but no luck.

Comment: Can you show how you are trying to build the list you are referring to?

Comment: I tried based on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620377/lua-reflection-get-list-of-functions-fields-on-an-object) question. I added more details to my post.

Comment: You mean that in that loop you have `key` assuming just two values: `name` and `__instance`? More specifically, in your Lua loop put only `print(key, " --> ", value)` and post the results.

Comment: `__instance       -->    userdata: 0xa03e170
name     -->    function: 0xa03cfe8`.

Comment: Mmm. Comment out the loop, try this and post what happens: `print("1:", o.name()); print("2:", o.textureId)`

Comment: The binding works, the output is what's expected, I can even break in the C++ function. (I tried anyway, I need `o:name()` since that's an instance method, and the properties are apparently handled differently). In the lualite code all I can see is pushlightuserdata calls. I don't know how it resolves the properties then, but it definitely does.

Comment: I fear that lualite doesn't provide a way to iterate over all the properties of a specific instance. You could try a Lua-side solution if your Lua code can be made to know the name of each property, but his entails some code duplication. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of `lualite`. I wrote the library to be minimalist and fast and did not foresee the need for reflection :) Anyway, what you are looking for can be found as 2 static members:

```
static ::std::unordered_map<char const*, detail::map_member_info_type,
  detail::unordered_hash, detail::unordered_eq> getters_;
static ::std::unordered_map<char const*, detail::map_member_info_type,
  detail::unordered_hash, detail::unordered_eq> setters_;
```

the `char const*` is the name of the property, the value being a `map_member_info_type`, which are essentially two pointers, one to a `lualite` stub, the other to the `C++` member function.

```
struct map_member_info_type
{
  lua_CFunction callback;

  member_func_type func;
};
```

If you like, I can make both members public. The way properties work is as follows:

A default getter is (usually) set in the wrapped class's instance table:

```
lua_pushcclosure(L, default_getter<C>, 2);

rawsetfield(L, -2, "__index");
```

This points to the default getter:

```
template <class C>
int default_getter(lua_State* const L)
{
  assert(2 == lua_gettop(L));
  auto const i(lualite::class_<C>::getters_.find(lua_tostring(L, 2)));

  return lualite::class_<C>::getters_.end() == i
    ? 0
    : (lua_pushlightuserdata(L, &i->second.func),
      lua_replace(L, lua_upvalueindex(2)),
      (i->second.callback)(L));
}
```

which looks for the name of the property (which is on the stack). That could be anything really and if it does not find the name, it returns 0, otherwise, it forwards the call to the `lualite` stub made for the member function, which then handles the arguments and the return value(s).

Comment: hi, thank you very much for answering and writing such a nice library :) I actually found these in the meantime. I also found a bug (sort of), where can I submit it?

Comment: @fish BTW, if you want repository write access, I can fix you up.

Comment: thanks, I do. Although I can't promise to commit anything right now, but I do have a larger project going on which uses lualite, so it might be beneficial in the future. Do you see my full email address at the issue?

Comment: @fish I've added you, hope this library works out for you. You can add your name to the header file.

Comment: thanks, that's very kind of you. If I commit anything useful I'll do that too.

Answer (score 0):

If you could tolerate having to list the property names in your Lua code, this could be a solution:

```lua
local GetPropertyList
do -- to make `property_names` "private" to GetPropertyList
    property_names = {
        ["SpriteComponent"] = { "textureId", "spriteCoordX", "spriteCoordY" },
        -- property names for other components, e.g.
        ["AnotherComponentName"] = { "propName1", "propName2" },
    }
    function GetPropertyList( object )  --[[local]]
        local component_name = object:name()
        local prop_names = property_names[component_name]
        if not prop_names then
            error( "unsupported component" )
        end
        local res = {}
        for _, p_name in ipairs( prop_names ) do
            local p_val = object[p_name]
            res[ #res + 1 ] = p_val
            -- or use this if you want a key-value map:
            -- res[p_name] = p_val
        end
        return res
    end  -- function
end  -- do


for k, v in pairs( GetPropertyList(o) ) do
    print( k, v )
end
```

Comment: Yeah, the idea was to use the information I provide to lualite as a primitive form of reflection - so I don't want to duplicate the property names, unfortunately. I will try to adjust lualite to construct the information while binding.

Comment: @fish Yeah, but I've also made some members public for you, so you can get the properties from the `C++` side.