# Get the list of variables loaded in Lua in C code

Tags: c, lua

I'm new to Lua and I'm modifying lua.c (the interpretor) to load a library and to add auto-completion.

Unlike this question : [Lua - Reflection - Get list of functions/fields on an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620377/lua-reflection-get-list-of-functions-fields-on-an-object) I want to retrieve the "functions" associated to an object in C (not in Lua).

So, in C, how can I get a list of the names of the variables loaded in Lua ? then for a given name (e.g. "Foo"), how can I get the names of the "functions" that can be called on that object (the functions are stored in a metatable isn't it ?)

Comment: Have you read the [C API](https://www.lua.org/pil/24.html)? I think what you want is some combination of [getting a global](http://pgl.yoyo.org/luai/i/lua_getglobal), [getting a metatable](https://www.lua.org/pil/28.2.html), and 
 [reading the table](https://www.lua.org/pil/25.1.html).

Comment: You should take a look at Mike Pall's advanced readline patch on the [Lua Power Patches](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaPowerPatches) page on the Lua Wiki. It has pretty nice auto-completion already.

Comment: @cyclaminist Thank you ! that solves my problem !

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment of cyclaminist", the advanced readline support patch does what I m looking for !